# I am trying to display a marquee widget from coin market cap in react but it is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, marquee

I am making an investment website using react and I am trying to use widgets from coinmarketcap but it seems not to be doing anything

```
import React from 'react'

const Coinwidget = () => {
  return (
  <>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
      src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js" 
  ></script>
  <div
    class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget"
    data-currencyid="1"
    data-base="USD"
    data-secondary=""
    data-ticker="true"
    data-rank="true"
    data-marketcap="true"
    data-volume="true"
    data-statsticker="true"
    data-stats="USD"
  ></div>
  </>
  );
}

export default Coinwidget
```